# How to install CarrierWave using Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I am trying to install CarrierWave, defined in my gemfile as:

```
gem "carrierwave", github: "carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave"
```

but I get:

```
unable to connect to github.com:\ngithub.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection refused\ngithub.com[1: 192.30.253.113]
```

I tried using the command:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

multiple times but the error remains. I checked IP in the address bar of the browser and it redirects me to github.com successfully.

When I tried to clone it manually:

```
git clone git://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave.git
```

this happened:

```
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection refused
```

And when I run:

```
git clone https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave.git
```

then it is successfully cloned.

I think there is somehow linked to HTTPs.

How can I resolve this?